# ThinkPad T420 intel i5 4 GB RAM freezes all the time I open some tab on browser

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, thinkpad

My laptop, a Thinkpad T420 with an intel i5 processor and 4 GB RAM works very slowly and freezes when I open some tabs, pages on browser. The laptop works slowly, sometimes,  also when I do another things like writing on notepad or when opening very few tabs on browser (1-3).

Is this a software problem? Or do you think this is a hardware problem? How can I check it?

I work with chrome browser for linux and Firefox. The problem exists in both browsers.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 updated

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu Linux 14.04 updated

Comment: Check system resources with `top` or `htop` and look for warning messages in `journalctl -k`. My guess is you've got insufficient memory.

Answer (score 1):

4GB isn't much by 2019 standards. Which distro do you use? Some would use a large part of your RAM and leave little for your application. Otherwise a T420 is a rather ancient machine, so hardware problems are quite likely.

When it comes to debugging such problems, your primary tool is a system monitor:

- Is the CPU speed coherent with the CPU specs? If somewhat lower, the CPU could be throttling due to temperature (cooling problems)
- Is the CPU temperature normal (<60°C)? Beyond 80°C you could have CPU throttling (cooling problems again).
- Is the CPU using all its cores? Is hyper-threading available on your CPU and is it enabled?
- Is there much free RAM? Is the system swapping?
- What are the top processes for CPU or RAM usage?

Comment: I'm sorry, my OS is Ubuntu Linux 14.04 upded.

Answer (score 0):

There should be not problem for this configuration as long as you don't have tons of services running in the background. Check the state of your system with the `top` command in a terminal. Otherwise, it might be a matter of cooling. Possibly the cooling tract needs a clean up. You can check the temperatures with the command `sensors` or similar. You may need to install sensor software first. If this is the case, run:

```
apt search sensor
```

and pick a suitable package.